# Congruence Modulo involving factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, congruences

How do I show that $23!\equiv 21! \pmod{101}$? I tried using a calculator but the numbers are so big that am finding it hard to prove. How can factorials be broken down so that they can be easily solved?

Comment: $23!-21!=(23)(22)21!-21!=21!((23)(22)-1)=21!(505)$. Note that $101$ divides $505$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: What is $\dfrac{23!}{21!}$? And what is that modulo $101$?

Comment: Am I allowed to divide the two or should I say (b-a)/n ?

Comment: @Ben: I’m not sure that I understand your question. I’m suggesting that you look at that if $x$ is the fraction in my answer, then you’re interested in proving the equation $23!=21!x\pmod{101}$. Knowing what $x$ is modulo $101$ turns out to make this easy.

Comment: $$ (23\cdot22)\cdot 21! \overset{\Large\text{?}} \equiv 21!  $$
Since the modulus $101$ is prime, we can cancel $21!$ from both sides and get
$$
23\cdot22 \overset{\Large\text{?}} \equiv 1
$$
Just figure out whether that last statement is true and then you should see what's actually going on here. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael: One doesn’t need the fact that the modulus is prime; one needs only the (arguably) more basic fact that if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{m}$, then $ac \equiv bd \pmod{m}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : ok, I see what you mean.  But the idea that one can cancel everything except $0$ does rely on the fact that the modulus is prime. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael: Nothing in this problem depends on having a prime modulus. It works fine if you change $101$ to $505$, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$23!-21!=(23)(22)(21!)-21!=(21!)((23)(22)-1)=(21!)(505).$$
Note that $101$ divides $505$.